# Capability to control content of the iframe size through the content's url - javascript to take advantage of this

Tags: javascript, html, css

EDIT: What's right below this has been answered - see the question below it for the current question that has arisen from that answer.

The below code makes the page fit the screen, and I can size the iframe to be any height or width that I want, and the page will not scroll. THis is what I want. However, I don't just want the page to cut the iframe off. I want the iframe to stretch/shrink to fit the browser window. How can I achieve this efficiently? Can it be done without javascript? If javascript is needed for this, please provide a beginner level explanation, or a good tutorial link; I'm new with JS.

Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <iframe id="myIframe" src="https://#.com" border="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">    
        </iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

EDIT! It just so happens that this particular page that I want to use in the iframe here offers a very interesting control feature in the url itself! The url allows size control. So this leads me to ask a new question, which involves using a javascript. My new question is this:

Can I use some sort of JS script to take advantage of the size control here in the url

```
<iframe id="myIframe" src="https://media.embed.ly/1/frame?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.twitch.tv%2Fgamemode_mc_&amp;width=1280&amp;height=1280&amp;secure=true&amp;key=0202f0ddb5a3458aabf520e5ab790ab9&amp;"
```

to dynamically force the size of the iframe content to match the user's browser window?

This will combine the solution to my original question with a secondary solution to provide the perfect fix for my problem here.

*(My goal here is actually to place this Twitch feed as a background to my webpage - resizing the actual content of the iframe is actually a very unlikely but seemingly possibly additional treat here!)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are attempting to accomplish can be done with the following in tour CSS

```
#myIframe {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
}
```

Comment: Well this works -_- Why did I miss that. Ah! I had preset iframe widths in the iframe itself to begin with when I tried this. THanks, I'll accept this once the time requirement is reached

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to stretch the content of iframe then.....

You will have to write css that will give proportional height and width to all elements in the iframe document

if the iframe href is not from your domain then there is no way to achieve this.

Overall, there is no way to stretch the content of page so that all things are visible on the screen without scrollbar.

Comment: Actually, That's not correct, although only because the webtool that generates the the page I'm looking at in the iframe extends a very interesting thing! The url actually allows for size control! Now, this means that I'll need a JS script to dynamically have the height and width in the url match the window size